# jQuery Fade in/out sequence

Tags: jquery, sequence, fade

http://jsfiddle.net/HQjSK/4/

i have a problem: first i had this code:

```
 $("#twitter").click(function () {
      $("#main_facebook, #main_linkedin, #main_spotify").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#main_twitter").fadeIn(500);
      });
      return false;
    });
```

The problem was that the fadeIn would start at the same time as the fadeOut. 
What i want is fist fadeOut and then start fadeIn

I made this changes:

```
$("#twitter").click(function () {
      $("#main_facebook:visible, #main_linkedin:visible, #main_spotify:visible").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#main_twitter").fadeIn(500);
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Now the problem is, that if #main_facebook is already hidden, #main_twitter will not fadeIn.

Thank!

Comment: Anyone? I am reading a lot of articles bun can't get it figured out..

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
$("#twitter").click(function () {
  $("#main_facebook:visible, #main_linkedin:visible, #main_spotify:visible").fadeOut(500)
  .queue(function () {
    $("#main_twitter").fadeIn(500);
    $(this).dequeue();
    });
  return false;
});
```